# Finding a cpu or disk-hogging process quickly in Windows?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

**Short**:

Best alternative of `ctrl-alt-1` -> `top` or `sudo iotop` in Windows?

**Long**:

Sometimes a server or workstation might seem to hang, due to either cpu-bottleneck or disk-bottleneck. How do I diagnose this the quickest and easiest on Windows? I'm looking for something which is available even if the system is on it's knees, for example the built in task-manager or procexp (the sysinternals tool) is too heavy. And it needs to be quick.

Or do I have to accept that it's not possible to work in a *nix:y way on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Get-Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849832(v=wps.620).aspx) powershell cmd for CPU:

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending | Select-Object -First 10
```

With diskIO things won't be as simple I'm afraid. There are some really nice powershell tools out there though, for example:  [Learn how to use Windows PowerShell to simplify collecting performance information from your servers.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/31/use-powershell-to-simplify-collecting-performance-information.aspx)